# cron job not running on Centos 6.3

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have created a cron job that runs a script which moves files from one location to another.
Here is my result after running `crontab -l`

> 0 6 * * 0 root /root/scripts/move.script.sh

move.script.sh has following lines of codes:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/rm -rf /home/user1/folder2/Monday/*
/bin/mv /home/user1/folder1/* /home/user1/folder2/Monday/
```

With this code, I first remove the stuff from last week in Monday folder and then copy stuff from user1's folder1.

How ever this job doesn't run at all.

I have checked with other cronjobs but they work fine and the problem is with this cronjob only.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong in here?

Answer (score 2):

The format of cron entries in `/etc/crontab` and cron daemon, located in `/var/spool/cron/$username` are different. In `/etc/crontab`, you have to specify the user-name under which the command will be executed, while in the later you don't have to.

The `crontab -l` command you executed shows you the cron entries for the user executing that command. It doesn't show you the `/etc/crontab` entries. In short, you have to remove the user `root` from the cron entry.

Edit the cron entry using the command

```
  crontab -e
```

Then replace your entry with the one below

```
  0 6 * * 0 /root/scripts/move.script.sh
```

Comment: Also the shell script most have executable and read permission for root user.

Comment: Thanks Daniel 
I'll check tomorrow if cronjob has completed correctly